# python Lists 'NoneType' error

Tags: list, python-3.x

I am trying to split the lists and copy them into 2 separate lists and I get:
"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

```
class example(object):
      def ex(self,nums):
             n = int(len(nums)/2)
             nums1 = nums[:n]
             nums2 = nums[n:]
```

Comment: `nums` is not a list... `nums` is `None`...

Comment: what does nums variable looks like prior to your splitting?

Comment: nums was going to be passed as a parameter to a function. So technically it would be null before the value is passed. How do I handle that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you verified that nums is indeed a list and that there is a value for n? It would be useful in the future if you could provide that code as well so users can give better help.

Also, I am not sure if it was just an error when you copied and pasted the code, but it will not work if it is on the same line.

By the way, **python uses None instead of null** which is why @Jeff Mercado mentioned this in his comment.

I have sample code that works:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
n = 2

nums1 = nums[:n]
nums2 = nums[n:]

print(nums1)
print(nums2)

Output:
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
```

**Edit to check if list is null**

Checking implicitly (PEP 8 recommended way):

```
if not nums:
    print("Nums is empty")
```

Checking explicitly (however this is frowned upon in python):

```
if len(nums) == 0:
    print("Nums is empty")
```

For more information on the built-in not type, see the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) for python 2.x and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) for python 3.x.

Edit again, now that you have completely edited your initial question..

```
class Example(object):

    def ex(self, nums):
        # Either use an if check or try/except
        if not nums:
            print("Nums is empty")

        try:
            n = int(len(nums) / 2)
            nums1 = nums[:n]
            nums2 = nums[n:]

            print(n)
            print(nums1)
            print(nums2)
        except TypeError:
            print("Exception: You would put your exception code here")


example = Example()

num_list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
example.ex(num_list1)

num_list2 = []
example.ex(num_list2)

num_list3 = None
example.ex(num_list3)
```

Output:

```
2
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
Nums is empty
0
[]
[]
Nums is empty
Exception: You would put your exception code here
```

**Additional Recommendations:**
1. To stick to normal conventions, capitalize your class name. This will help differentiate it from a normal function call and an object instantiation.

Comment: Edited again since you uploaded an entirely new segment of code. I hope the information I have given you has helped. I now recommend playing around with it to help you learn.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.